# How to display picture from memory in Django?

Tags: python, django, memory, image

I know how to show picture as a page from memory just using like this:

```
import cStringIO

mStream = cStringIO.StringIO(picBin)

return HttpResponse(mStream.getvalue(),"image/jpg")
```

But what if I don't want to show the picture as a page, instead I want to show it within a page, say using  in HTML, does someone has an idea what I should set the "src" if the picture is loaded from memory?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to base-64 encode the image contents into a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
data_uri = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'
data_uri += mStream.getvalue().encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
```

Now you can shove `data_uri` into the `src` attribute of an image.

Comment: It's working fine even if I use something like: <a href="{{data_uri}}">

Comment: You can encode anything with a MIME type into a data-URI. It's pretty cool, but the problem is that browsers don't cache the data-URI images

Comment: In `python 3.4`, you need to write: `data_uri = b'data:image/jpg;base64,'`