# How do you use R in Python to return an R graph through Django?

Tags: python, r, django

I'm trying to run the following R code through my Django application with the end result being a printed R graph in a Python Django webpage. Here is the code for R.

```
t=read.table(file=file("request.FILES['fileUpload']"))
colnames(t) <- c('x', 'y')
t = data.frame(t)
fit1 = lm(y ~ x, data = t)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(x=t$x, y=t$y, xlab="x", ylab="y", main="Simple Linear Regression", xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,6), par=20)
abline(fit1, col="red")
```

Here is something like what I am trying to achieve in the Django function.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
import pandas as pd

def upload_files(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        upload = pd.read_table(request.FILES['fileUpload'])
        << Run R Code Here and return the graph >>
        response = RGraph
        return response
             OR
        return render(request, 'Regression/index.html', {'graph':response})
    return render(request, 'Regression/index.html')
```

HTML code is as follows.

```
<html>
    <title>Import File</title>
        <body>
            <h1>Import File</h1>
                <hr>
            {% if graph %}
                <img alt="my base64 graph" src="data:image/png;base64,{{graph}}" />
            {% endif %}
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="file" name="fileUpload" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

As always, thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry but What is the question here?

Comment: I edited the title to make the question clear.

Comment: Just create a `<img src="">` in your template with the `src` pointing to the graph generated by `R` should be enough.

Comment: But how do I create the graph through Python. I'm researching rpy2 right now and I'm getting errors with the importr and lm functions.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently **rpy2** does not provide a direct function which can return a file object to python. So what i recommend is:

#### 1) Set a path to save your R image files

- On your **settings.py** define a variable where your **R** scripts/images should be saved

  ```
  STATIC_R = 'r_plots'
  ```

#### 2) Build a model/form to handle the file management based on your settings

- Model

  ```
  from django.conf import settings

  class RScript(models.Model):
      script = FileField(upload_to=settings.STATIC_R)

      @property
      def script_path(self):
          return os.path.basename(self.script.name)
  ```
- Remember (from docs): **FielField.upload_to**: *A local filesystem path that will be appended to your MEDIA_ROOT setting to determine the value of the url attribute.*
- Form

  ```
  class RScriptForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Metal:
          model = RScript
          fields = ('script',)
  ```

#### 3) Running you code from upload

- Receive your **R script** and save it

  ```
  my_plot_script = '''
      t=read.table(file=file("{path}"))
      colnames(t) <- c('x', 'y')
      t = data.frame(t)
      fit1 = lm(y ~ x, data = t)
      par(mfrow=c(1,1))
      png(filename="{path}.png")
      plot = plot(x=t$x, y=t$y, xlab="x", ylab="y", main="Simple Linear Regression", xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,6), par=20)
      abline(fit1, col="red")
      dev.off()
  '''

  def my_view(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
          form = RScriptForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
              form.save()
              (...)
  ```
- Now that we have script saved let's try to running it with **rpy2**

  ```
  my_plot_script = '''
      t=read.table(file=file("{path}"))
      colnames(t) <- c('x', 'y')
      t = data.frame(t)
      fit1 = lm(y ~ x, data = t)
      par(mfrow=c(1,1))
      png(filename="{path}.png")
      plot = plot(x=t$x, y=t$y, xlab="x", ylab="y", main="Simple Linear Regression", xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,6), par=20)
      abline(fit1, col="red")
      dev.off()
  '''

  def my_view(request):
      context = {}
      if request.method == 'POST':
          form = RScriptForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
              form.save()
              import rpy2.robjects as robjects
              robjects.r(my_plot_script.format(form.instance.script_path))
              context['graph'] = form.instance.script_path + '.png'
              return render(request, 'Regression/graph.html', context)
  ```
- on your template

  ```
  <html>
      <title>Import File</title>
          <body>
              <h1>Import File</h1>
                  <hr>
              {% if graph %}
                  <img alt="my base64 graph" src="{{graph}}" />
              {% endif %}
              <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
              </form>
          </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: Could you show me how to do this with the code that I posted? Please and thank you.

Comment: Ok. Just give me some minutes :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to figure this out. I added the index.html HTML code in the OP.

Comment: @Poppins586 can you just say which of those line from the R script/func is the one generating the image to plot? I'm not familiar with R

Comment: one generates the plot and the other puts linear regression on the plot. The two lines that do that are the last two lines in the code that I posted.--- plot(x=t$x, y=t$y, xlab="x", ylab="y", main="Simple Linear Regression", xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,6), par=20)
abline(fit1, col="red")

Comment: Your whole graph(file) function is written in R. I'm getting syntax errors >.<

Comment: Ok. Now i got it. The @Shang Wang guy was right. You will need to save the plot as just a image on a folder covered by your static config. and then you just pass the string/name of the file to the __static__ tag on the template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90251/discussion-between-vyscond-and-poppins586).

Answer (score 3):

1. For this you can use the interface between R and Python given in the [RPy2` python package](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/). This allows you to run a R session alongside a python session, and being able to run R commands from within python and getting back the result.
2. Alternatively, you can run R as a commandline script on the server, have a look at `Rscript` to get this working. This script could produce a png based on a number of input arguments. Python could then pick up the png and send it back to the user.
3. As a third alternative, you could run R via `Rserve`, and create a connection to it to get the plotting done. For example see [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyRserve/manual.html).

Solution 3 is a bit overkill, but allows you to use R on a different server than your Django instance. Solution 1. is quite flexible, but more complex. Finally, solution 2. is the simplest solution, but sometimes lacks flexibility, especially if lot's of interaction between R and Python is needed.

Comment: Could you possibly show how I may go about doing this in code? This answer did not help me much.

Answer (score 1):

If you `install.package('magick')` in your R instance then you can use `rpy2` to get the image data back to Python as follows (I've used a simplier plot function):

```
from io import BytesIO

import PIL.Image as Image
import rpy2.robjects as ro

def main():
    r = ro.r

    r('''
        library("magick")
        figure <- image_graph(width = 400, height = 400, res = 96)
        plot(c(1,2,3))
        image <- image_write(figure, path = NULL, format = "png")
    ''')

    image_data = ro.globalenv['image']

    image = Image.open(BytesIO(bytes(image_data)))

    return image


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = main()
    image.show()
```

You can then use the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487698/how-to-display-picture-from-memory-in-django) to render the image within a Django template.